# Java - How can i set the time when the pc has to do an operation?

Tags: java, timer, runtime, freeze, shutdown

I'm doing a programm that shuts down (or make sleep) your pc at the selected time.

At the moment i've used a "barbaric" way to do this, i used a cicle that controls what time is continuosly and if the hour and minutes are the same of the selected values, the operation start, else, the cicle go on.

```
private void btn_SetActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    hour_Decided = Integer.parseInt((String) cmb_Hours.getSelectedItem());
    minutes_Decided = Integer.parseInt((String) cmb_Minutes.getSelectedItem());
    int current_Hours = 0;
    int current_Minutes = 0;
    boolean ok = false;
    do {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        current_Hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        current_Minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        if (current_Hours == hour_Decided && current_Minutes == minutes_Decided) {
            ok = true;
            if (rdbtn_Standby.isSelected()) {
                try {
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Sleep");
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(StandbyForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            } else if (rdbtn_Spegni.isSelected()) {
                try {
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("shutdown -s -t 0");
                    System.exit(0);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(StandbyForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }while (ok == false);
}
```

With this method there's a problem. The thread freez and you cant do nothing untill the programm has finished. The unique way to stop it is close the process.

There's any other solution? Like a timer or something ...

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Given code is not executed every second but continuously

Comment: oh, yes that's right, i've just said it badly

Comment: http://quartz-scheduler.org/, but SO isn't for questions asking for external tools or libraries so I didn't really say that.

Comment: Probably [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) is a way to go.

Comment: One solution is to set a [timerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) to periodically check if it's time to shut down

Comment: So in every way you pick, you have to do a millisecond delay...that's pretty boring... because, what if you set a "tomorrow" hour? 
this is going to be hard for a highschool user like me :|

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). You'll have to figure out how far in the future the "go" time is, and then schedule your task (everything that you do when `ok == true`) for that many seconds in the future with one of the `ScheduledExecutorService.schedule()` tasks.